# How do I change which microphone and webcam device is being used on Firefox?

Tags: firefox

When I use Firefox to start a video call, Firefox asks me to select a camera device and a microphone device, and to grant the website permission to use those devices:

[image: Screenshot]

If I tick the checkbox "Remember this decision", Firefox will always use the selected camera and microphone. How do I change the selection of the camera and the microphone after this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way is to revoke the permissions on that website and reset them, so that you get the permission prompt again, in which you can choose a different device.

To reset the permissions for a website, click on the icons to the left of the URL in the address bar, the ones that look like a padlock, a configuration icon and a camera. Then click on the "x" next to the permissions "Use the Camera" and "Use the Microphone" to reset the permissions. Then refresh the page.

[image: Screenshot]

Once you've done that, you will be prompted again to choose a camera and a microphone device when you refresh the page.